# Carto.JS - Pop up closes when mouse hovers out of feature

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js

As per the CARTO docs I am using the following code to trigger a info pop up when the user's mouse hovers over a feature:

```
const popup = L.popup({ closeButton: false });
    ecosystem.on(carto.layer.events.FEATURE_OVER, featureEvent => {
      popup.setLatLng(featureEvent.latLng);
      if (!popup.isOpen()) {
        popup.setContent(featureEvent.data.name_2);
        popup.openOn(map);
      }
    });
```

However, the info pop up doesn't close when the user's mouse is moved out of the feature's bounds. The user has to click for the windows to close. Is it possible for the info pop up to only display when the mouse hovers over the feature, and closes automatically?

[Here is a working example.](https://storage.googleapis.com/leaflet_maps/Ecosystems/2011_threatened_ecosystems/threatened_ecosystems_index.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are only attaching a handler for the `featureOver` event, but not to the `featureOut`. If you check the example at the end where events are assigned:

```
  function setPopupsHover() {
    populatedPlacesLayer.off('featureClicked');
    populatedPlacesLayer.on('featureOver', openPopup);
    populatedPlacesLayer.on('featureOut', closePopup);
  }
```

I also recommend you to update to the last version of CARTO.js.